# How can I specify the individual edge color?

Tags: scidraw

In package `SciDraw` the `LineColor` option can be used to set the color of the figure axis

```
<<SciDraw`
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
   },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 10},
  YPlotRange -> {-1, 1},
  LineColor -> Red
  ],
 CanvasUnits -> Centimeter,
 CanvasSize -> {10, 6.18},
 CanvasMargin -> {{1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}
 ]
```

Now I want to make the Y edges in left and right have the different color, and I use the code below, but that produces an error

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
   },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 10},
  YPlotRange -> {-1, 1},
  YLineColor -> Red,
  YYLineColor -> Blue
  ],
 CanvasUnits -> Centimeter,
 CanvasSize -> {10, 6.18},
 CanvasMargin -> {{1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}
 ]
```

How can I make the edges in `SciDraw` have the different colors?

Comment: If you cannot find anything better, perhaps you can draw your own frame.

Comment: I read the  `SciDraw`  documentation (Version 0.0.7, page 89) and the options `XLineColor` and `YLineColor` is described. Maybe these options is still under development.

Comment: It seems like something is wrong ... you could write an email to the SciDraw developer and ask about this option.  Point out that the option is described on page 89 of the manual, but it does not seem to be present.  There is no `XLineColor` symbol created when loading the package.

Comment: I have sent a mail yesterday but haven't got a response yet.  Maybe Dr. Caprio is busy... I'm looking forward to the next release :-)

Comment: The author of `SciDraw` replied me yesterday. He said that the linecolor options for XY are not defined, but he will define them or fix the manual in the future.